# JPlayer not playing video in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mp3, mp4, jplayer

I have JPlayer for audio and video files on TytonSound.com

for some reason, IE doesn't want to play video files. The video files are available in .mp4, .ogv and .webm

Does anyone know why these files aren't being played?

For an example page you can use http://tytonsound.com/commercials.php

The bottom list item is a video.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add another format, M4V.
I didn't actually create an M4V file, I just used the MP4 one, and told the script that it was MP4 and M4V. See Below.

```
{
    title : "Wawahte",
    m4v : "/video/wawahte.mp4",
    mp4 : "/video/wawahte.mp4",
    webmv :/video/wawahte.webm", 
    ogv : "/video/wawahte.ogv",
    poster : "images/poster.png" 
}
```